# Defining required hash values in a javadoc

Tags: java, groovy, javadoc

Let's say I have a Java method like this:

```
void configure(Map<String, String> values) {
    assert values.containsKey("x"), "Missing parameter x"
}
```

Is it possible to specify in the JavaDoc comment that "x" is a required value in `values`?

Comment: Do you mean more formally than in a sentence?

Comment: You can always write `* @parameter values ... bla bla bla ... The key "x" must be present.`

Comment: `throws AssertionError if "x" is not a key in values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the method's signature, and assuming `x` is a mandatory parameter, but there are other (optional) parameters that the `Map` may contain, you could communicate this in the signature itself via

```
void configure(String xValue, Map<String, String> optionalValues = [:]) {

}
```